# Scroll in jquery

Tags: jquery

I need to append the content in particular div when the particular div visible in view port.

But the content append multiple times whenever the div visible in view port.

How to restrict that.  I need to append the content in div only one time.

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {

  var viewport = {
    top: $(window).scrollTop(),
    left: $(window).scrollLeft()
  };
  viewport.right = viewport.left + $(window).width();
  viewport.bottom = viewport.top + $(window).height();

  if ($("#style-based-products").is(":visible")) {
    var elemtHeight = $("#style-based-products").height(); // Get the full height of current element
    elemtHeight = Math.round(elemtHeight);
    var bounds = $("#style-based-products").offset();
    bounds.top = bounds.top + elemtHeight;
    bounds.right = bounds.left + $("#style-based-products").outerWidth();
    bounds.bottom = bounds.top + $("#style-based-products").outerHeight();
    if (!(viewport.right < bounds.left || viewport.left > bounds.right || viewport.bottom < bounds.top || viewport.top > bounds.bottom)) {

      self.getProducts();

    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Where you are appending the content?

Comment: please add `HTML` code also.

Comment: You can use a global variable that is initiated before the window.on('scroll') handler like e.x. `var contentAppended = false;` and before self.getProducts() write `if(contentAppended){return;}  contentAppended=true;` . So this code `if(contentAppended){return;} checks if you have appended your content and if yes, exits and will not proceed to call self.getProducts() (which i guess is where you load the content and append it). If the if fails it will mark the contentAppended as yes and move to load the content